# CSS2DRenderer with WebGLRenderer not working

Tags: three.js

I started working with this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label) where both, a CSS2D Renderer as well as a WebGL Renderer is used - it works fine.
Now, I want to load object files and add CSS Labels to it. I started with the [OBJ-Loader Example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj2.html). There, the renderer is created as follows (all the following code snippets refer to the loader example):

```
        initGL: function () {
            this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
                canvas: this.canvas,
                antialias: true,
                autoClear: true
            } );  .....
```

Thre renderer is called as follows:

```
        render: function () {
            if ( ! this.renderer.autoClear ) this.renderer.clear();
            this.controls.update();
            this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
        }
```

My problem is that I do not know how to integrate the CSS2 Renderer. I simply tried to add the new labelrenderer to the same positions of the WebGLRenderer but it seems not to work:

```
        initGL: function () {
            this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
                canvas: this.canvas,
                antialias: true,
                autoClear: true
            } );  //same code as before
           this.labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer(); 
           document.getElementById( 'example' ).appendChild(this.labelRenderer.domElement );....
```

I tried to update the render also at the same position of the WebGL Renderer:

```
render: function () {
                if ( ! this.renderer.autoClear ) this.renderer.clear();
                this.controls.update();
                this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
                //same code as before
                this.labelRenderer.render(this.scene,this.camera);
            }
```

The result: the WebGL renderer seem to work (the model is loaded) but the webgl renderer is not working... I do not get any error message but I simply do not see any label. What do I wrong? I create the label as follows:

```
var earthDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
earthDiv.className = 'label';
earthDiv.textContent = 'MYLABEL IS NOT SHOWN';
earthDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
var earthLabel = new THREE.CSS2DObject( earthDiv );
earthLabel.position.set( 0, 3, 0 );
scope.scene.add(earthLabel );
```

Comment: What's the difference between `this.scene` and `scope.scene`?

Comment: Please try to demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/).

Comment: What about error logs ?

Comment: No errors occured!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that  the CCS2 Object was added to the wrong div:

```
document.getElementById( 'example' ).appendChild(this.labelRenderer.domElement );
```

Of course, both, the canvas from the WebGL Renderer and the dom of the label Renderer have to be added to the same parent (the element `example` was the dom of the webgl renderer)

Thank you soo much for your support!